# How to limit number of posts in index.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an index.php with loop

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

// render post here

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Now I want to limit number of post by N on the page and create
a link to next/previous N posts.

A small code snippet is very appreciated.

UPDATE

What about the URL string? I want to make functionality similar to SO
where query is determined by URL for example

get next twenty questions from the recent

https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=2&sort=active

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that in this way:

```
query_posts( 'posts_per_page=5' );
```

References: 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Ok thank you. Now if you look at the SO homepage and press NEXT you get new URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=2&sort=active do I have build that parameterized url manually on my site as well? I believe that query_posts does not update that URL in the address bar. It only provides filtering.

Comment: You have to used the 'paged' param on that query and then use paginate_links function to display links. Check this out: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

Comment: Glad to help! Also, remember you have WordPress Answers sister site: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do they have greater audience than SO?

Comment: Definitely no, but more specialized for sure :)

Comment: From Wordpress _**Note:** This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes._